# Find String by part of string

Tags: python

Is it possible to find line in file by part of it

As example:

```
I'm the good boy
I'm the bad boy
I'm the really good boy
```

Can i find the line by searching `I'm the boy` without writing `good` or `bad`

i need to catch the three lines

i tried

```
str = "iam good boy"
if "iam boy" in str:
    print ("yes")
else:
    print ("no")
```

Comment: There are two lines. Which one do you want to find?

Comment: No, this won't work.  `in` only works on exact substrings.

Comment: @BuddyBob i need to find both

Answer (score 1):

Using [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), you can do something like this:

```py
import re

strs = (
    "I'm the good boy",
    "I'm the good girl",
    "I'm the bad boy",
    "I'm the really good boy")
    
for s in strs:
    if re.match("I'm the .+ boy", s):
        print("Yes, it is, yeah")
    else:
        print("It's actually not")
```

prints

```
Yes, it is, yeah
It's actually not
Yes, it is, yeah
Yes, it is, yeah
```

Comment: I have file with thousand of lines, is there anyway to find the lines withour specifying `\\w+` because i don't know where exactly be the missing word ?

Comment: You can replace `\\w+` with `.+`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found worked.

I had a text file, which had these two lines (which I understand you have):

```
I'm the good boy
I'm the bad boy
```

The I wrote this (with comments to explain how it works):

```
with open("testing.txt", 'r') as file:#Open the text file, do stuff and then close it when done
    row_counter = 0
    for row in file: #Go through each line in the file
        row_counter +=1
        if "I'm the" in row: #Check to see if a line in your file if it has "I'm the"
            if "boy" in row: #Narrows down to find a line that also contains "boy"
                print(f"Line {row_counter}") #In forms you which line(s) have "I'm the" and "boy" in them
```

The output is:

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

meaning both lines in the text file have "I'm the" and "boy" in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it using `re.search` to find the match. Also `enumerate` to keep the index and only return yes is all matches occur.

```
import re
stro = "iam good boy"
target = "iam boy"

def finder():
    for i,e in enumerate(target.split()):
        if re.search(e, stro):
            if  i == len(target.split()) - 1:
                return("yes")  
        else:
            return("no") 
  
finder()
# Yes
```